# How to Wait in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript

Here is a question about what I would think would be a simple pattern in node js.

Here is my example in coffeescript:

```
db_is_open = false

db.open ->
  db_is_open = true

wait = ->
wait() until db_is_open
```

And here again in javascript:

```
var db_is_open = false;

db.open(function() {
  db_is_open = true;
});

function wait() {};
while (not db_is_open) { wait()};
```

This does not work at all because the while loop never relinquishes control, which I guess makes sense.  However how can I tell the wait function to try the next callback in the queue?

Comment: You can't wait, you can only use callbacks

Comment: you are basically asking how to write asynchronous node.js code in a synchronous fashion, which is a hot issue with lots of new projects and ideas. Check this link, they are tons though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139381/node-js-async-libs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you waiting, and not just using a callback that runs inside of the function passed to `db.open`? This is pretty much idiomatic Node code:

```
db.open(function() {
  // db is now open, let's run some more code
  execute_db_query();
});
```

Basically, you should simply follow the patterns laid out in [the documentation](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native#readme).

Comment: Well if I only want to open the connection pool one time then what you are doing would not make sense.  I am familiar with the callback pattern.  

My problem is with the initial setup of the app.  The app needs to set itself up before anything can be run, this includes setting up the database, and it needs to be done synchronously.

Maybe this is not possible but is there any way to yield control flow back to the event loop?

Comment: Also you don't want to do open and close every time it is wasteful.  Here is what Chris (the guy who wrote the library you linked to) said " The general pattern is to open the db connection before you start the web framework and then leave it open." [here](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/issues/477)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just start the web framework in the `db.open` callback? If that doesn't answer it, you might just want to ask him directly for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I guess the "wait pattern" as I described above is just not possible in Node.js at the moment.

To put it another way though, it would be like saying, require("somelib"); , and then somelib has some asynchronous resources it has to set up.  Well how can my code that is importing that module know that "somelib" is finished setting up or not?

Comment: Whatever IO resources your module has to setup, you can pass a callback to it and it can tell you when it's ready. You never want to implicitly start accessing IO in your module, users will not like that.

Comment: So in Node, there is no way to take "fs.readFile", and create "fs.readFileSync".  If you want synchronous I/O, is it explicitly not allowed if the library you are using is asynchronous?  I mean, I understand what you are saying I am just wondering if it's possible to get Synchronous I/O.  I mean it's in the standard libraries.

Comment: @BradC That's exactly right. When something is asynchronous in JavaScript, there's no way to make it synchronous. Things like `fs.readFileSync` are possible only because the implementation is in C++.

Answer (score 4):

I like to use the [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async) when I have bits of code that need to run synchronously.

```
var async = require('async');

async.series([
  function(next){
    db.open(next)
  }
, function(next){
    db.loadSite('siteName', next)
  }
], function(err){
  if(err) console.log(err)
  else {
    // Waits for defined functions to finish
    console.log('Database connected')
  }
})
```