# CoffeeScript pass child process result to variable

Tags: coffeescript

I am trying to understand why my code is not passing `stdout` to `taskList`, inside `childp.exec` the `msg.send` works fine but `taskList` is always empty string.

```
cmd = "cd #{directory}; \
       bundle exec rake -T | perl -lne 'print if /^rake (clear|integration):/'"
taskList = ""
childp = require 'child_process'
childp.exec cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) =>
  if error?
    msg.send ":x: Error to get rake task lists"
    return
  else
    msg.send stdout # Works fine, I can see a list of rake tasks I want
    taskList = stdout

msg.send typeof taskList # Return 'string'
msg.send taskList        # empty string is sent back
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Isn't exec asynchronous? If so, you will have to wait for the callback to run before accessing `taskList`

Comment: @Thilo How should I wait for in then? I mean in coding, is there a synchronous version of exec?

Comment: You need to move the code into that callback (after `taskList = stdout`). Or use something like a Promise.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139381/node-js-async-libs

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Wait in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881892/how-to-wait-in-node-js)