# How to avoid deep nested code with mongoose / node?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to improve the readability of a biggish nodejs app that uses a lot of mongooose. The problem is that with a lot of dependent queries the callbacks get out of hand.

What are the practices of handling this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three common solutions for your problem.

First one is [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) lib.

Second one is using Promises. There are more then one implementation of promises in node.js. I know three implementations:

- [node promise](https://github.com/kriszyp/node-promise)
- [vow](https://github.com/dfilatov/jspromise)
- [Q promise](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/)

Third one is to use [Fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers). There is [fibers promise](https://github.com/lm1/node-fibers-promise) library that do all the tricky work for you.

There was plenty of similar questions before. For example, [check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139381/node-js-async-libs).

All this libraries do the same thing - they make node.js asynchronous code pretty and readable. So, just choose one that looks simpler for you.

As for me, I prefer `async.js` lib.

**Update:** `mongoose.js` have its own build-in promise - [mpromise](https://github.com/aheckmann/mpromise). You can access it as `mongoose.promise`. But whenever you call `exec()` function on a query in `mongoose` it returns you a promise. I never actually used `mongoose.js` promises except for the `REPL`, but you may give it a try.

Comment: fibers-promise is a whole different beast as the other libs, because it's based on fibers. I'd mention fibers as a third, distinct approach. Big list of Promises/A+ implementations is here: https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/blob/master/implementations.md

Comment: @MerynStol You're right, fibers-promise is a whole different thing. I edited my answer using your advice.