# Run async process in Node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, process

I understand that node.js has a lot of functions that runs async, like the I/O functions.
I am trying to run two modules that I created in a async way, these modules only use the CPU, not an I/O request.

For example, I have something like this: I call `f2()` first, but I want it so if `f1()` ends first it won't wait until `f2()` has finished; is that possible?
This is only an example, but I will use this calling another js file.

I tried to write this using the `process.nextTick()`, but I don't know if that's the real solution.

```
function f1(){

    for (i=0;i< 100;i++){

    }
    console.log("f1")
}

function f2(){

    for (i=0;i< 100000000000;i++){

    }
    console.log("f2")
}


f2();
f1();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an async module for doing just this

look at the parallel example in the following post [node.js async libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139381/node-js-async-libs)

```
async.parallel([
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... }
], callback);
```

the wiki for async.js https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: this wait until the first func ends why? async.parallel([
                function (callback) {
                 var i = 0; 
                 for (i;i< 100000000;i++){
               
              }
                    callback(null, i);
                },
                function (callback) {
                 var i = 0; 
                 for (i;i< 100;i++){
               
              }
                    callback(null, i);        
                }
            ], 
            function (err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(data);
            });